# sqlite-jdbc for SQLite v2.X

Tags: java, linux, sqlite, jdbc, centos

We are having lot of SQLite databases (of version 2.X) in the Cent OS linux servers. Now there is a need to read those database content using java and do some operations on it.

I couldn't find sqlite jdbc compatible to this SQLite v2.X version.

If I try to use the latest jars available here (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc), I got this error,

```
Error :[SQLITE_NOTADB] File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)
```

Where can I find jdbc driver jar for SQLite v2.X or is there any other work around for this ?

Comment: Do you need to keep these files in v2 format?

Comment: @CL, These are already existing files in production. Currently we are using perl DBD:SQLite2 for accessing these files. Now there is a requirement to do this from java. Once I'm able to read the content of v2 SQLite, we planned to move all data away from it to some NoSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a database file from SQLite 2 to SQLite 3, you can use the command-line shells of both versions to dump the database as SQL commands, and recreate it:

```sh
sqlite db2.sqlite .dump | sqlite3 db3.sqlite
```

There is no SQLite 2 driver for any modern language (except Perl and PHP).

Comment: I know this option but this doubles the disk space and so I want to take this as a last option. But as you said if there is no driver, this is the only way.